# How to set carousel snap point?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to build a row with scrollable snap effect with carousel, everything is fine but one thing I want to leave a little bit of the previous index card so it looks like this

[image]

But it only happened when the last index is mounted but if not it will look like this

[image]

It has no gap with the side of the screen

Here is my code

```
Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.h),
        child: CarouselSlider(
          items: data
              .map<Widget>(
                (e) => card(e),
              )
              .take(itemCount)
              .toList(),
          carouselController: carouselController,
          options: CarouselOptions(
            padEnds: false,
            autoPlay: false,
            height: carouselHeight,
            enableInfiniteScroll: false,
            enlargeCenterPage: false,
            disableCenter: true,
            viewportFraction: 0.32,
            // aspectRatio: 2.0,
            initialPage: 1,

            autoPlayCurve: Curves.bounceIn,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.w),
    child: CarouselSlider(
      items: data
          .map<Widget>(
            (e) => card(e),
          )
          .take(itemCount)
          .toList(),
      carouselController: carouselController,
      options: CarouselOptions(
        padEnds: false,
        autoPlay: false,
        height: carouselHeight,
        enableInfiniteScroll: false,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        disableCenter: true,
        viewportFraction: 0.36,
        initialPage: 1,
        autoPlayCurve: Curves.bounceIn,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```